# ¿Emojis a color en chrome html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hay alguna forma de que los emojis se vean a color, yo intenté usando una fuente que añadí en css es twiter emoji pero ya averigüé y en chrome solo aparece a blanco y negro, para poner los emojis usé emoji one area y me salen a color los mismos emojis de twitter. Alguien tiene idea de qué puedo hacer.
O sea, miren lo que hago:

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'twit';
 src: url(fuente/twitter.ttf);

}
```

Miren cómo queda:
https://prnt.sc/pz57o2

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta he incluye [un ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Por el código que has puesto, estás utilizando un `font-icon` es decir, una fuente de iconos. Al ser una fuente, obtiene las propiedades de una y, por lo tanto, deberás tratarla como tal.

Para cambiar su color deberás hacerlo como si trataras de modificar el color de un texto, con `color`.

De igual manera, si quisieras aumentar su tamaño, deberás hacerlo como si fuera un texto, con `font-size`.

Solo deberás tener cuidado de no modificar el `font-family`

Comment: Pero, lo que pasa, es que esta fuente debería ser a color(los emojis con todos sus colores normales) porque usa un formato SVG pero Chrome no acepta ese formato. Quiero saber si puedo hacer algo para que se vean los SVG y así no se vea a blanco y negro. En otros navegadores como firefox se ve a color.